# maven and aspectj plugin - tests hang

Tags: maven, aspectj

I am using the aspectj-maven-plugin when trying to weave my aspect into my application. The problem I am seeing is that the compilation and weaving seems to run fine, but whenever it gets to the test phase it simply hangs. I have included a section from my pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is the output I get:

```
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to /home/***/target/classes
[INFO] [aspectj:compile {execution: default}]
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/***/src/test/resources
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to /home/***/target/test-classes
[INFO] [aspectj:test-compile {execution: default}]
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/***/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
  T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.example.MyTest
```

Has anyone else seen this behaviour / know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting this here in case someone did as I was doing.  The reason the test was hanging was because of the aspect pointcut.

```
call(* *.*(..))
```

After this I had an advice that was called before the pointcut.  However this creating a cyclic condition, and was hanging my tests.  doh!